# Telerik MVC Menu Control - Auto Width

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am trying to use the Telerik MVC Menu control (as a button bar), but can't seem to be able to set the width to auto-generate.  What I mean is, the menu continues to the end of the DIV.  I would like the menu to only be as wide as the sum of the button widths.  Actually, the Telerik demo is doing the same thing as my menu is doing:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/menu/sitemapbinding
(Look at how the menu continues on to the right of "Other product lines").

Here is my menu:

```
    @{ Html.Telerik().Menu()
            .Name("case-history-button-menu")
            .ClientEvents(events => events.OnSelect("onCaseHistoryMenuBarSelect"))
            .Items(menu =>
            {
                menu.Add()
                    .Text("Add a Response").HtmlAttributes(new { id = "cases-history-addresponse" } ); @*Sets the ID HTML attribute so we can access it *@
                menu.Add()
                    .Text("Add a Comment").HtmlAttributes(new { id = "cases-history-button-addcomment" }); ;
                menu.Add()
                    .Text("Back to Cases").HtmlAttributes(new { id = "cases-history-button-back" }); ;
            })
            .Render();
    }
```

I do realize that I could just hard code my width ... but as I add or remove buttons (programatically) I want the menu to resize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Telerik MVC menu is rendered as an `<UL>` element. The latter has block display by default which means it occupies all the available space. You can override the display to "inline-block" and then the menu should be sized as you need it to:

```
   @{ Html.Telerik().Menu()
            .Name("case-history-button-menu")
            // set the display to inline-block
            .HtmlAttributes( new { style = "display: inline-block" } )
    }
```

Have in mind though that older versions of IE won't accept inline-block display. You may need "inline" if you must support older IEs.

Comment: @Atanas Korchev can you have  look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7414387/413670